# Load complex json in hive using jsonserde

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to build a table in hive for following json

```
{
    "business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA",
    "hours": {
        "Tuesday": {
            "close": "17:00",
            "open": "08:00"
        },
        "Friday": {
            "close": "17:00",
            "open": "08:00"
        }
    },
    "open": true,
    "categories": [
        "Doctors",
        "Health & Medical"
    ],
    "review_count": 9,
    "name": "Eric Goldberg, MD",
    "neighborhoods": [],
    "attributes": {
        "By Appointment Only": true,
        "Accepts Credit Cards": true, 
        "Good For Groups": 1
    },
    "type": "business"
}
```

I can create a table using following DDL,however I get an exception while querying that table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS business (
 business_id string,
 hours map<string,string>,
 open boolean,
 categories array<string>,
 review_count int,
 name string,
 neighborhoods array<string>,
 attributes map<string,string>,
 type string
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde';
```

The exception while retrieving data is "ClassCast:Cant cast jsoanarray to json object" . What is the correct schema for this json? Is there any took which can help me generate correct schema for given json to be used with jsonserde?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me that the problem is `hours` which you defined as `hours map<string,string>` but should be a `map<string,map<string,string>` instead.

There's a tool you can use to generate the hive table definition automatically from your JSON data: https://github.com/quux00/hive-json-schema

but you may want to adjust it because when encountering a JSON Object (Anything between {} ) the tool can't know wether to translate it to a hive `map` or to a `struct`.
On your data, the tool gives me this:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
 attributes struct<accepts credit cards:boolean, 
       by appointment only:boolean, good for groups:int>,
 business_id string,
 categories array<string>,
 hours map<string:struct<close:string, open:string>
 name string,
 neighborhoods array<string>,
 open boolean,
 review_count int,
 type string
)
```

but it looks like you want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
     attributes map<string,string>,
     business_id string,
     categories array<string>,
     hours map<string,struct<close:string, open:string>>,
     name string,
     neighborhoods array<string>,
     open boolean,
     review_count int,
     type string
    ) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

hive> load data local inpath 'json.data'  overwrite into  table x;
hive> Table default.x stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=416,rawDataSize=0]
OK
hive> select * from x;
OK
{"accepts credit cards":"true","by appointment only":"true",
  "good for groups":"1"}    
  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA    
  ["Doctors","Health & Medical"]    
  {"tuesday":{"close":"17:00","open":"08:00"},
   "friday":{"close":"17:00","open":"08:00"}}   
    Eric Goldberg, MD   ["HELLO"]   true    9   business
Time taken: 0.335 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

A few notes though:

- Notice I used a different JSON SerDe because I don't have on my system the one you used. I used [this one](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde), I like it better because, well, I wrote it. But the create statement should work just as well with the other serde.
- You may want to convert some of those maps to structs, as they may be more convenient to query. For instance, `attributes` could be a struct, but you'd need to map the names with a space in them like `accepts credit cards`. My SerDe allows to map a json attribute to a different hive column name. That is also needed then JSON uses an attribute that is a hive keyword like 'timestamp' or 'create'.

Comment: Hive does have support of JSON, but not at this complexity. I have been using this SERDE: **"org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe"** in many use cases and its awesome.

Comment: Hi @Roberto_Congiu I could successfully create a table with both your and amazon's serde. However I can't access complex types in a query e.g. select categories[0] from x limit 1; thorws exception "[] not valid on non-collection types '0': string"

Comment: That is odd because it works fine for me:
    hive> select categories[0] from x limit 1;
    OK
    Doctors
So, are you getting that error with both serdes ?
It may depend on the data, if you use select categories[0] but the categories array is empty, you'd get an error. You can try 
    select IF(size(categories)>0 , categories[0], null) from x;