# Converting json data to normal rows in hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I am very new to Hive and i am working on below problem but i couldn't solve it. Please help me.

I have below type of json records.

```
{"issues":[{"key":"COV-2073","labels":[ "java","db"]}]}
```

And i would like to un nest it or convert it like below.

```
Key          labels
"COV-2073"  "java","db"
```

I have used below kind of query but i am unable to get my desired output.

```
select v2.key  from demo_example as d lateral view json_tuple(d.a1,'issues') v1 as issue lateral view json_tuple(v1.issue,'key') v2 as key;
```

Even i am okay with below kind of output also.

```
 Key          labels
"COV-2073"    "java"
"COV-2073"    "db"
```

Please help me to solve above one.

Comment: actually you dont need to do this. you have to prepare table in json format so you get the desired output.

Comment: @sahildesai I have very complex json file. so i have followed http://thornydev.blogspot.in/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html this article to do. So there is no other way to do it as a query?

Comment: it's 5 years old doc I think now we have some better way to do this task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927116/load-complex-json-in-hive-using-jsonserde

Comment: @sahildesai I update question, can you check once please?

Comment: Can it be done in SparkSQL or only in Hive?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in SparkSQL

```
//data.json
{"name":"John","age":"30","cars": [{ "name":"Ford", "models":["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]}, {"name":"BMW", "models":["320", "X3", "X5"]}, {"name":"Fiat", "models":["500", "Panda"]}]}

//SparkSQL
>>> sqlContext.sql("""select name,age,col1.name, col2 from json.`data.json` lateral view explode(cars) v1 as col1 lateral view explode(col1.models) v2 as col2""").show()

+----+---+----+-------+
|name|age|name|   col2|
+----+---+----+-------+
|John| 30|Ford| Fiesta|
|John| 30|Ford|  Focus|
|John| 30|Ford|Mustang|
|John| 30| BMW|    320|
|John| 30| BMW|     X3|
|John| 30| BMW|     X5|
|John| 30|Fiat|    500|
|John| 30|Fiat|  Panda|
+----+---+----+-------+
```

When some rows of json do not have values for specific columns and if you would like to show `NULL` then use `lateral view outer` instead of `lateral view`.

As an example, the below json has 2 entries, one with all details and one with no cars, models etc.

```
{"name":"John","age":"30","cars": [{ "name":"Ford", "models":["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]}, {"name":"BMW", "models":["320", "X3", "X5"]}, {"name":"Fiat", "models":["500", "Panda"]}]}
{"name":"Dough","age":"90"}
```

In this case, using outer produces `null` for entry `Dough`

```
>>> sqlContext.sql("""select name,age,col1.name, col2 from json.`data.json` lateral view outer explode(cars) v1 as col1 lateral view outer explode(col1.models) v2 as col2 order by col2""").show()

+-----+---+----+-------+
| name|age|name|   col2|
+-----+---+----+-------+
|Dough| 90|null|   null|
| John| 30| BMW|    320|
| John| 30|Fiat|    500|
| John| 30|Ford| Fiesta|
| John| 30|Ford|  Focus|
| John| 30|Ford|Mustang|
| John| 30|Fiat|  Panda|
| John| 30| BMW|     X3|
| John| 30| BMW|     X5|
+-----+---+----+-------+
```

If you want all your models as an array, then

```
>>> sqlContext.sql("""select name, age, car.name as car, car.models from json.`data.json` lateral view outer explode(cars) v1 as car""").show()
+-----+---+----+--------------------+
| name|age| car|              models|
+-----+---+----+--------------------+
| John| 30|Ford|[Fiesta, Focus, M...|
| John| 30| BMW|       [320, X3, X5]|
| John| 30|Fiat|        [500, Panda]|
|Dough| 90|null|                null|
+-----+---+----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cloudera's Hive JSON serde to parse JSON and load them as CSV. You can download the Serde from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByJLBTmJojjzMlhUWGxVMWtXdEU). Add the jar into your Hive classPath or from the hive terminal.

Then you can create a hive table as

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(issues ARRAY<STRUCT<key:STRING,labels:STRING>>) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe';
```

Now load your data into the table and test. Now write your select statement as

```
select issues.key,issues.labels from TEST;
```

You will get your desired output as

```
["COV-2073"]    ["[java, db]"]
```